# R - replace a list of numbers in a data frame with a repeating sequence of numbers

Tags: r

I have some data similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c('1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'),
                 month = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'))
```

I need to replace the numbers in the 'month' column with a repeating pattern of 1:12 like this:

```
  year month
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     3
4     1     4
5     1     5
6     1     6
7     1     7
8     1     8
9     1     9
10    1    10
11    1    11
12    1    12
13    2    1
14    2    2
15    2    3
16    2    4
17    2    5
18    2    6
19    2    7
20    2    8
21    2    9
22    2    10
23    2    11
24    2    12
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 12 - year * 12 + month

Comment: The simplest way is `df$month <- 1:12`, but that assumes your data always has exactly 12 rows per year

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(month = (as.numeric(as.character(month))-1) %% 12 + 1)`

Comment: try df$month <- seq(1:12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that every year has all 12 months then `df$month <- 1:12` is enough. If you think that the years have an inconsistent number of recorded months, but that the months that are recorded are consecutive, then you can use dplyr's mutate to simply add each row's integer position for each `year`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    mutate(month = 1:length(month))
```

Otherwise you should probably use the values of `month` by converting them to integers. Keep in mind that `data.frame` turns strings into factors, so first add `stringsAsFactors = F` to your call to `data.frame`:

```r
df <- data.frame(year = rep(1:2, each = 12),
                 month = as.character(1:24),
                 stringsAsFactors = F
                 )
```

Then do the following, which returns remainder of division by 12, then replaces remainder 0 with 12:

```r
df %>% 
    mutate(month = as.integer(month) %% 12, 
           month = ifelse(month == 0, 12, month)
           )
```